# Codeigniter HTML list helper breaks the DB class

Tags: php, codeigniter

**Model method**

```
public function my_friends_list($myId)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("CALL myFriendsList($myId)");
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $data['friends'] = $this->friends_model->my_friends_list(1);
    $this->load->view('friends/index', $data);
}
```

**View**

```
<?php
    $list = $friends;
    echo(ul($list));
?>
```

If I use the above everything works. But if I change the view to this:

```
<?php
    //$list = $friends;
    echo(ul($friends));
?>
```

**I get the following error message**

Unable to select the specified database: My_Database_Name

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\system\database\DB_driver.php

I know that I could simply use the view that works but I want to understand what's going on. Are they not equivalent??

Edit: After I go back to the original view, the only way to clear the error is to restart MySQL module.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a stored procedure so just go to your "config/database.php" and change with below code.

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
to 
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
and pconnect should be true
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
```

Hope this will help.